How to show Multiple Attachment in Adaptive Card Power Automate
I have Power Automate with Adaptive Card. like the cut in the picture,
enter image description here
how can I get Attachment from sharepoint data and display it as a link in Adaptive Card? I use this coding but only 1 Attachment appears even though each data has 2-4 Attachments.
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "Attached Files",
      "weight": "bolder",
      "size": "medium"
    },
    {
      "type": "FactSet",
      "facts": [
        {
          "title": "File Name:",
          "value": "@{variables('attachmentsArray')[0]['name']}"
        },
        {
          "title": "Link:",
          "value": "[Open File](@{variables('attachmentsArray')[0]['url']})"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.2"
}


{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "Attached Files",
      "weight": "bolder",
      "size": "medium"
    },
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "Files:",
      "wrap": true
    },
    {
      "type": "Container",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "ColumnSet",
          "columns": [
            {
              "type": "Column",
              "width": "stretch",
              "items": [
                {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "text": "File Name",
                  "weight": "bolder"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "Column",
              "width": "auto",
              "items": [
                {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "text": "Link",
                  "weight": "bolder"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "$data": "@{variables('attachmentsArray')}",
          "type": "ColumnSet",
          "columns": [
            {
              "type": "Column",
              "width": "stretch",
              "items": [
                {
                  "type": "TextBlock",
                  "text": "${name}",
                  "wrap": true
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "type": "Column",
              "width": "auto",
              "items": [
                {
                  "type": "ActionSet",
                  "actions": [
                    {
                      "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                      "title": "Open",
                      "url": "${url}"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.2"
}

I tried to find references and found code like this, but the variables ${name} and ${url} do not display data from "$data": "@{variables('attachmentsArray')}", the result is like this
enter image description here
